# how to open Word Document in browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open binary Word Document file in browser, not from physical path. With the given below code I can open PDF files in browser, but not other files.

CODE:

```
byte[] obFile = null;
obFile = (byte[])fds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["File"]; 
String aFileName = "abc"; 
Response.Expires = 0; 
Response.ClearContent(); 
Response.Buffer = true; 
Response.BufferOutput = true; 
Response.ContentType = "application/msword;name=abc.docx"; 
Response.AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary"); 
Response.AddHeader("content-length", obFile.Length.ToString()); 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=abc.docx"; 
Response.CacheControl = "public"; 
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251); 
Response.OutputStream.Write(obFile, 0, obFile.Length); 
Response.End();
```

Comment: buffer must be off, and if you call this from aspx page then probably its going to make it gzip and fail to load it. Need to make a handler ( an .ashx file) t send it. What error you get ? I think that one bug here is the obfile. Is this correct taken ?

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of Word is to open document outside browser window. This is client side setting and can't be changed from server side code.

Check out [How to configure Internet Explorer to open Office documents in the appropriate Office program instead of in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;162059) on the support site how to reconfigure **your** machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flash/ Silverlight library to display document. Microsoft also have Office Web Apps (which require a license) that can show and edit office document on browser